# Azure Native Client Authentication

Tags: c#, authentication, azure

I have created a native app on Azure but I'm not sure how to get the access token with just the client ID. I was using a web app earlier in which I had a client ID and secret and used those to authenticate.
I've tried using AcquireTokenSilentlyAsync but I cant do that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the AcquireToken method like below. This will pop up a browser dialog to ask for your credentials.

```
private static string GetToken(string authority, string clientId, string redirectUri)
{
    var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority, validateAuthority: false);
    var result = authContext.AcquireToken("https://graph.windows.net",
        clientId, new Uri(redirectUri), PromptBehavior.Auto);

    return result.AccessToken;
}
```

If you want to authenticate without prompting the user, have a look at the resource owner credential grant. This is explained in [this article](http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2014/07/08/using-adal-net-to-authenticate-users-via-usernamepassword/) by Vittorio Bertocci.

Comment: I think I might have chosen the wrong one between native client and web app. Does a native client have to use credentials? Is there a way to do something like client secret like in web apps?

Comment: That depends on who you are trying to authenticate. If it's the user of the native client, then use one of the grants I described. If you don't care about the user, but only want the application to access the API, then look into the Client Credentials grant. This is to authenticate the client application. You won't have any info on the user.